# Can not merge df2 to df1 despite shared values in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have really strange situation. I try to merge two DataFrames using one common column like below:

```
df1.merge(df2, on = "customer_id", how = "left")
```

Nevertheless, no columns from df2 join df1 even though they share customer_id. In both DataFrames customer_id is same type "int". How it is possible? What can I do ?

Comment: Please add your df1, df2 sample data.

Comment: I can not add sample data because these datasets are really huge, I ask you whether you had similar situation at your job ?

Comment: Run `df1.head()` and `df2.head()` to get only five line of each dataframe. And, if column number is big try catching some of them with `customer_id` included.
We cannot fix the problem if don't see your data.

Comment: you have to show at least the head of datasets, ok keep just two columns: -> df1[["customer_id", "col2"]] and df2[["customer_id", "col3"]]

Comment: print `df1.dtypes` and `df2.dtype`s and add the output to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the error message to your post. Also it would be good idea to paste some of your data so people can test what is going on.

For instance:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'data1':['a','b','c','d','e','f']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[2,5,3,4,3,1], 'data2':['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff']})
```

Now we can test what's going on:

```
df1.merge(df2, on = "customer_id", how = "left")
```

Seems to work. So most likely there is something amiss in your data structure.

I personally dislike the syntax of **df.merge**, I suggest using **pd.merge** instead:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on= 'customer_id')
of 
out = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on= 'customer_id', right_on = 'customer_id')
```

For more on merging see [pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)